# Question doesn't appear to be a duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

This older question [Is the magnetic field zero inside an ideal conductor carrying a current?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270220/) is explicitly about a regular conductor, but has been marked as a duplicate of a question about superconductors.  In addition, it has a useful answer.

I suspect the title referring to an "ideal conductor" is a bit confusing.  But I think it should not be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. Is there a specific reason you made a meta post instead of simply voting to reopen it?

Comment: Interface blindness, I'm afraid.  Done now...

Comment: @BowlOfRed You may want to leave a comment below that post. This should help prevent the occasional automatic/inertial "Leave closed" vote.